# python and ipython threading.activeCount()

Tags: python, multithreading, ipython

I have a module that imports threading and uses [threading.activeCount()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.activeCount) to determine when all threads are done. I initially wrote my module using the standard python interpreter. Using my module in a script is fine, however when importing my module in ipython and calling a function that depends on threading.activeCount(). My function never returns.

Code:

```
for dev in run_list:
   proc = threading.Thread(target=go, args=[dev])
   proc.start()

while threading.activeCount() > 1:
   time.sleep(1)
```

I noted that when first importing threading with the standard interpreter and calling threading.activeCount(), only 1 thread is counted:

```
>>> import threading
>>> threading.activeCount()
1
>>> threading.enumerate()
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140344324941568)>]
```

However when using the ipython, the initial count is 2:

```
In [1]: import threading

In [2]: threading.activeCount()
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: threading.enumerate()
Out[3]: 
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140674997614336)>,
 <HistorySavingThread(Thread-1, started 140674935068416)>]
```

This module is used by various people using various interpreters to work, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this (preferably still using threading)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) your threads instead of relying on `activeCount`:

```
threads = []
for dev in run_list:
    proc = threading.Thread(target=go, args=[dev])
    proc.start()
    threads.append(proc)

for proc in threads:
    proc.join()
```

Comment: How do i then check if all of the threads are finished in def main?
Right now i have a While loop running until ActiveCount == 0

How do i check that with join?

Comment: @Steelzeh join waits for the thread to finish. After the join you know the thread is finished without checking some other way.

Comment: Well what if i want to check for when all the threads are finished, so i can display a message or something :)

Comment: @Steelzeh Yes, simply show the message after joining all the threads.